# How to monitor the HDFS replication progress of the cluster?

Tags: hadoop, replication, monitor, progress, hdfs

Is there a specific log for the replication ?
Is there a command to use to view the current status, what it is doing, copy speed, etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop Log Directory contains 2 logs mapred-logs and hdfs-logs. Although I haven't done what you're trying to do, I'm sure you will find what you need if you go through the hdfs-logs.

Comment: You're not making small edits to many of your answers in order to artificially bump them, are you?